# Unexpected match with java regex

Tags: java, regex, non-greedy

I want to find xml tags of type x in a text that

- are empty (contains only spaces)
- may or may not have attributes

Also something like this

```
<x>  </x>
<x a="v">  </x>
```

I use following regular expression in combination with the Matcher find function.

```
<x.*?> +</x>
```

I get matches that I don't expect. See following test case

```
@Test
public void sample() throws Exception
{
    String text = "Lorem <x>ipsum <x>dolor sit amet</x> </x>";
    String regex = "<x.*?> +</x>";

    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(text);
    assertFalse(matcher.find());
}
```

The test fails. Instead this is true

```
assertTrue(matcher.find());
assertEquals("<x>ipsum <x>dolor sit amet</x> </x>", matcher.group());
```

Does the find function not support the non-greedy operator or what goes wrong here?

PS I know that there is a plethora of different ways to process xml data. But this is not the point here.

Comment: [One good reason not to venture down this road](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `.*?` quantifier means that it will find as few characters as possible to satisfy the match, it doesn't mean that it will stop searching at the first `>` it finds. So in your example, the `<x.*?>` will match all of:

```
<x>ipsum <x>dolor sit amet</x>
```

With all the characters between the first `x` and the the final `>` satisfying the `.*?`. To fix this, you can simply change your pattern to:

```
<x[^>]*> +</x>
```

On a side note, it's been stated many times before, but [you should not use regular expressions to parse xml/html/xhtml](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1715579).

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the hint. I know that regex is not the right tool for xml processing but sometimes - if you have to make a litte fix to thausends of files - a quick text replace is tempting.